# I can't make my inkscape black-themed

Tags: themes, inkscape

I followed many tutorials but my inkscape just stays default white.
I don't know why! I tried it for version 0.92.1 and 0.92 --> 0 success.

[Dark theme zip file download](http://www.mediafire.com/file/bunqu4bqt88bzqa/Inkscape+0.91+dark+theme.zip)

Answer (score 3):

I found this method or solution.

1. Make a temp directory in say `/home/$USER/inkscape_dark`
2. Change into that directory and clone the repo from github:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/alma4rebi/Inkscape-0.91-dark-theme.git
   ```
3. Move into the repo `cd Inkscape-0.91-dark-theme`
4. Now follow these steps accordingly using a terminal:

   1. Untar the file `tar -cvf Inkscape\ 0.91\ dark\ theme\ linux.tar.gz`
   2. `cd Inkscape\ 0.91\ dark\ theme\ linux`
   3. `cd Set\ dark\ theme/`
   4. `sudo cp etc/gtk-2.0/gtkrc /etc/gtk-2.0/`
   5. `sudo cp share/icons/icons.svg /usr/share/icons/`
   6. `sudo cp share/themes/Default/gtk-2.0-key/gtkrc /usr/share/themes/Default/gtk-2.0-key/`

Now launch inkscape and you should see your dark theme.

**Note:**

To return to bright theme use the contents of the `Return bright theme` folder also found therein.

Source:

https://github.com/alma4rebi/Inkscape-0.91-dark-theme